# Moving Website-URL

Tags: urls, 404-error

I tried moving my website according to [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) (after trying it the wrong way - by just changing the URL in WordPress settings)

but now that I did, my homepage is still there but the rest of my pages are not displayed anymore (404).

What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To change every links, I suggest you to use [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/).

> If you move your WordPress website to a new domain name, you will find that internal links to pages and references to images are not updated. Instead, these links and references will point to your old domain name. This plugin fixes that problem by helping you change old urls and links in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `wp-config.php` and add the constants below to overwrite the values from your settings inside the database.

```
// Home URL of your WordPress.
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/wpbeta' );
// URL to the WordPress root dir.
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wpbeta' );
```

After this check your site again, if it works, check the settings, maybe also via an mySQL management tool such as phpmyadmin to find old URLs in table `wp_options` to switch to the new one or execute

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'oldsite.com','newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'oldsite.com', 'newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'oldsite.com','newsite.com');
```

*Note replace `wp_` if you set another prefix in old database.*

As hint, you can use the plugin 'Search & Replace' for doing that, search and also replace.

WordPress save also the url in each content, post, if you have images, media files etc. in your content. That's needs that you replace all urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to Login to Admin Dashboard, please visit Permalink Page and click on Save without changing any values. 
It works sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I use the excellent WP Clone plugin by WP Acadamy ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ ) to move sites from one place to another. It takes care of all of the URL adjustments without having to go into the database manually.

Very easy to use; install on both source and target systems, then backup the source, and restore to target. Works every time for me, and is much simpler than manual adjustments to databases.